# concurrent application

Tags: erlang, distributed, mnesia, yaws

i have used erlang for the passed five month and i have liked it now it is my time to write down a concurrent application that will interact with the YAWS web server and mnesia DBMS and to work on a distributed system may any one help me with a sketchy draft in Erlang?

i mean the application should have  both the sever end and the client end where by the server can accept subscriptions from clients, Forwards notifications from event processes to each of the subscribers, accept messages to add events and start the needed processes, can accept messages to cancel an event and subsequently kill the event processes. whereas the client should be able to ask the server to add an event with all its details,ask the server to cancel an event, monitors the server (to know if it goes down) and shut down the event server if needed. The events requested from the server should contain a deadline

Comment: i suggest that you provide more information about the kind of application you are planning on working on with these several applications. The distribution part of the project makes erlang a good choice but let the programmers here understand more about your exact need.

Comment: thank you Joshua i have added more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spend some time browsing github, you can find projects corresponding to your description:

http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&biw=1405&bih=653&q=site%3Agithub.com+erlang+yaws+mnesia&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=